# How to silently start Sinatra + Thin?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I have a Sinatra::Base webservice which I want to start from a command line Ruby program, so I have this:

```
# command line program file
require 'mymodule/server'

puts "Running on 0.0.0.0:4567, debugging to STDOUT..."

MyModule::Server.run! bind: '0.0.0.0', port: 4567, environment: :production
```

This works as expected but it throws out:

```
$ myscript
Running on 0.0.0.0:4567, debugging to STDOUT...

== Sinatra/1.3.1 has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop

127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011 18:44:55] "POST /images HTTP/1.1" 200 360 0.0133
...
```

And I want it to be silent, and let me output what I want. For example, if I start it not daemonized I want to just see some message from the command line program and the log output, something like:

```
$ myscript
Running on 0.0.0.0:4567, debugging to STDOUT...
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2011 18:44:55] "POST /images HTTP/1.1" 200 360 0.0133
...
```

Also would like to silently shutdown it, hiding:

```
== Sinatra has ended his set (crowd applauds)
```

One last question, is this the best option to start a sinatra app with thin from inside an application code(ruby script in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off Sinatra logging with

```
set :logging, false
```

http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

As far as whether or not this is the best way to start a sinatra app... You might want to look at the "foreman" gem, and the "Procfile" (which Heroku.com uses) as an example:

http://ddollar.github.com/foreman/

Comment: If using SinatraBase, you have to do it inside the class declaration... http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps

Comment: You could also try the enable/disable-style setting of options

Comment: You can see https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/faf2efc670bf4c6076c26d5234c577950c19b699/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1415 that it's not possible to silence the shutdown (or startup) messages (unless you reopen stderr, but seems inadvisable).