# Disable Sinatra standard output

Tags: ruby, sinatra

For security reasons I don't wish to have Sinatra print every URL its requested in standard output, I've tried using `set :logging, false` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987989/1112669) using:

```
class SweetAppName< Sinatra::Base
    set :show_exceptions, false
    set :environment, :production
    set :logging, false
```

However when I run the app using rackup and thin, I still see the request logged to the terminal:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [26/May/2015:09:32:34 -0700] "GET /not-a-real-url HTTP/1.0" 404 - 0.0452

How can I turn these off?

Comment: If you are submitting sensitive data as part of the URL, you should know that HTTP packets can be intercepted. An attacker will then be able to read the URLs from the HTTP packets. You should probably use HTTPS, where the entire packet is encrypted, including the URL.

Comment: I am using HTTPS, however when NGINX passes the request upstream it does so as a HTTP request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you start your app with `rackup`, [Rack will add some middleware, including logging](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28tutorial%29-rackup-howto#automatic-middleware). You can prevent this by using the quiet option (`-q` or `--quiet`) to `rackup`, i.e. from the command line:

```
$ rackup -q
```

You can include this option in your `config.ru` if you want, so you don’t have to remember typing it every time you start your app. The [first line that starts with `#\` is parsed as options](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28tutorial%29-rackup-howto#config-file-syntax), so you can have a `config.ru` like this:

```
#\ --quiet

# other middleware etc...
run SweetAppName
```

If you use the classic Sinatra app style you will need to add the `set :logging, false` line, otherwise Sinatra will add its own logging. With the modular style (like you are using in the question) this setting defaults to `false` so you shouldn’t need it.